# How do I ExchangeService.FindItems to find all emails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, exchangewebservices

We have just switched to Microsoft Exchange Online (EOP and EOP2) Emails are working fine.

Right now, I just want to open a mailbox, scan all the emails and return simple information like `Sender` or `MailDate` etc

All I need is a simple working example. The closest I have gotten is below

```
FindItemsResults<Item> items = await serviceInstance.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "to:" + sEmail, new ItemView(15));
```

But this gives me this error

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FindItemsResults<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item>>' to 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FindItemsResults<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item>'`

```
        string sEmail = "xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.co,";
        string sPassword = "*********";
        string sResult = "";

        ExchangeService serviceInstance = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

        //Provide the  account user credentials
        serviceInstance.Credentials = new WebCredentials(sEmail, sPassword);//ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"].ToString());

        try
        {
            // Use Autodiscover to set the URL endpoint.
            serviceInstance.AutodiscoverUrl(sEmail, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback); //works up to here

            //error here
            FindItemsResults<Item> items = serviceInstance.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "to:" + sEmail, new ItemView(15));

            //no error here but can't do a foreach on "items"
            //var items = serviceInstance.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "to:" + sEmail, new ItemView(15));

            sResult = "Found:" + "\r\n";

            foreach (EmailMessage msg in items)
            {
                sResult += msg.Subject + "\r\n";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            serviceInstance = null;
            sResult = ex.Message;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong, things used to be so simple?

I am using

- VS2017, ASP.Net (Standard 4.6.1)
- Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard (v4.0.30319)

I have tried numerous examples from here and other sites to no avail.

Does anyone have a really simple working example, please

Comment: We have an older version, where we do casting of the item before trying to process it : `if (item is EmailMessage) { ProcessMail((EmailMessage)item); }` Maybe this can help.

Answer (score 1):

djack

I test your code, The following error is obtained in the serviceInstance.FindItems method.

The parameter queryString is only valid for Exchange Server version Exchange2010 or a later version.

So, you should create an exchange 2010 or a later version of exchange server.
Below is the detailed code.

```
 //The parameter queryString is only valid for Exchange Server version Exchange2010 or a later version.
        ExchangeService serviceInstance = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        //Provide the  account user credentials
        serviceInstance.Credentials = new WebCredentials(sEmail, sPassword);//ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"].ToString());
        try
        {
            // Use Autodiscover to set the URL endpoint.
            serviceInstance.AutodiscoverUrl(sEmail, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback); //works up to here
            //error here
            FindItemsResults<Item> items = serviceInstance.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "to:" + sEmail, new ItemView(15));
            //no error here but can't do a foreach on "items"
            //var items = serviceInstance.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "to:" + sEmail, new ItemView(15));
            sResult = "Found:" + "\r\n";
            if (items != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items.Items.Count);
                foreach (EmailMessage msg in items.Items)
                {
                    //sResult += msg.Subject + "\r\n";
                    Console.WriteLine(msg.Subject);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("is null");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            serviceInstance = null;
            sResult = ex.Message;
            Console.WriteLine(sResult);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("fhdfhk");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Best Regards,

Evan

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var items = serviceInstance.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "to:" + sEmail, new ItemView(15));    
var emailMessages = items.Items.Cast<EmailMessage>();
```

or

```
var emailMessages = items.Items.OfType<EmailMessage>();
```

then your `foreach` should work.